# How to store cout in string and then output the string to console?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, iostream

I am trying to store the output of my program in a file, and even though I know there are various much simpler methods, I want to solve the problem using strings since I would like to know the logic behind it.

So far, I understand the implementation:

```
std:: stringstream s;
s << "string";
```

and I know at some point I will have the following code

```
cout << s.str()
```

but how do I store my program output in the string stream without providing the string itself? Put another way, how do I redirect the cout statements within my program to a string?

Comment: What you've asked for is what your code snippet does. Show the actual code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: If you're asking how to change `cout` so that output will go to your string without changing the code, you can't.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can use `s << ` like you would use cout. That's great, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, you can. See the answer I just posted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: how is that "without changing the code"?

Comment: @ThomasWeller by "*without changing the code*", I assumed Mark meant changing all of the `operator<<` calls to write to an `ostringstream` object instead of to `cout`. That is not necessary. Yes, making the code write to a string instead of the console is a code change, but rerouting `cout` to use a different output buffer is a much smaller change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to redirect `std::cout` to a `std::string`, you can use the [`cout.rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) method to give `std::cout` a different buffer to write to, such as the buffer of a `std::ostringstream` (or a `std::ofstream`, etc).

The above linked documentation provides the following example of exactly this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream local;
    auto cout_buff = std::cout.rdbuf(); // save pointer to std::cout buffer

    std::cout.rdbuf(local.rdbuf()); // substitute internal std::cout buffer with
        // buffer of 'local' object

    // now std::cout work with 'local' buffer
    // you don't see this message
    std::cout << "some message";

    // go back to old buffer
    std::cout.rdbuf(cout_buff);

    // you will see this message
    std::cout << "back to default buffer\n";

    // print 'local' content
    std::cout << "local content: " << local.str() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Learn something new every day.  I had no idea the C++ standards committee had already anticipated this need.